# Nginx nginx_substitutions_filter variables

Tags: nginx, substitution

Is there a way to make a response (body) rewrite using a variable as source string ?
I tried whit nginx_substitutions_filter but It doesn't work.

```
set $a mysourcestr;
subs_filter $a mydeststr;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution using lua instead subs_filters. In nginx configuration file I added the following directives

```
set $a mysourcestr;
set $b mydeststr;
body_filter_by_lua_file /path/lua/scripts/subs.lua;
```

then I wrote a lua script very simple

```
#!/usr/bin/lua
-- /path/lua/scripts/subs.lua
response_body = ngx.arg[1]
response_body = response_body:gsub(ngx.var.mysourcestr,ngx.var.mydeststr)
ngx.arg[1]=response_body
```

Comment: This might not work if the response body was chunked. In that case you'd need to keep the whole response in memory (not recommended at all) or use streaming regex replacement.